# Javascript prototype extension method

Tags: javascript, prototype, micr

I have a prototype model where I need to include the following extension methods into the prototype:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
}
```

Example:
[JS]

```
sample = function() {
    this.i;
}

sample.prototype = {
    get_data: function() {
        return this.i;
    }
}
```

In the prototype model, how can I use the extension methods or any other way to create extension methods in JS prototype model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling the new method on string:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
}
```

should be as simple as:

```
alert("foobar".startsWith("foo")); //alerts true
```

For your second example, I assume you want a constructor that sets the member variable "i":

```
function sample(i) { 
    this.i = i;     
}

sample.prototype.get_data = function() { return this.i; }
```

You can use this as follows:

```
var s = new sample(42);
alert(s.get_data()); //alerts 42
```

Comment: i need to add tha startswith methos inside the sample prototype..

hw to do tat...

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you want then

Answer (score 1):

Constructor functions should begin with a capital letter though.

```
function Sample(i) { 
    this.i = i;     
}

var s = new Sample(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how correct this is, but please try this code. It worked in IE for me.

Add in JavaScript file:

```
String.prototype.includes = function (str) {
    var returnValue = false;

    if(this.indexOf(str) != -1){

        returnValue = true;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```